# Find records WHERE substring number is less than specified number in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database where numbers are added in the records as substring like "NYC: 120000000", "San Fransico: 800000", "Chicago: 10000000" etc in the population column.

How can I fetch Records where a number in the substring is less than or greater than a specific number?

Like

`` SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE `population` < 10000000 ``

So I should get "San Fransico: 800000"

Comment: Separate the columns and normalize the database.

Comment: Storing multiple atomic bits of data in a single string column is a *very* bad idea. You'll always be performing *unsargable* operations and forcing the engine to scan all rows.

Comment: hint:  substring_index

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If the data has to be in such a format you could use `substring_index` as suggested in comments

```
select * from cities 
where cast(substring_index(city_value,':',-1) as decimal) > 10000;
```

It looks like `:` is a standard delimiter in this field.

`Substring_index` returns a substring of a string before a specified number of delimiter occurs.  In this case, the `-1` parameter returns everything to the right of the `:` delimiter

[substring_index Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/func_mysql_substring_index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring_index with delimiter space starting from the end with position -1.
To sort by numerical order so that 9 comes before 10 we have to cast to integer.
As you can see it takes a lot of manipulation to extract the 2 values from the column. It would definitely be simpler and faster to have 2 separate columns.

> ```
> create table cities(
>   city varchar(100)
>   );
> insert into cities values
> ('NYC: 120000000'), 
> ('San Fransico: 800000'), 
> ('Chicago: 10000000');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   LEFT(
>     city, 
>     CHAR_LENGTH(city) 
>     - LOCATE(
>       ' ', 
>       REVERSE(city))
>     - 1
>     )
>   as city
> ,
>
> SUBSTRING_INDEX(city,' ',-1) population
> from cities
> order by
> cast(
>   substring_index(city,' ',-1)
>   as unsigned)
> ```
>
> ```
> city         | population
> :----------- | :---------
> San Fransico | 800000    
> Chicago      | 10000000  
> NYC          | 120000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1cb3ffb65cc5086c97330b0f7bcc906d)*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+ you can use REGEXP_REPLACE:

```
select population, REGEXP_REPLACE(population, '[^0-9]+', '')  
from cities
where  REGEXP_REPLACE(population, '[^0-9]+', '') < 10000000;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0fa0a734260ec4b07c4f0bbe717e1068